# executing os.system python commands after invoking a singularity exec command via os.system

Tags: python, os.system, singularity-container

so I have a python program that invokes singularity exec on a .sif file via os.system. Then on the next line of my program, I use os.system again to attempt to run a python script.  I assumed that this would start up the singularity, and then run my script from it, however currently it just runs the exec command, brings me into the container, and then hangs (it does not execute the python command).

Does anybody have any advice or experience with this issue?

Thank you.

Comment: A good question includes a [mre] -- the shortest possible code someone else can run to see the problem themselves, or modify to test their fixes.

Comment: That said -- _in general_, `os.system()` shouldn't be used at all. The `subprocess` module provides far more control, and ditches some of the bad decisions baked into `os.system()`'s design (as into the design of the `system()` function in C, which is every bit as bad). Responsible C programmers don't use `system()` anymore. Responsible Python programmers shouldn't use `os.system()` either.

Answer (score 0):

Singularity exec runs a *single, specified command*, it does not change the execution environment to that of the singularity image.

If you need an interactive session, use: `singularity shell my_image.sif`

If you need to run multiple commands, write a shell script and use that: `singularity exec my_image.sif my_script.sh`

Alternatively, use singularity to run your python script. Then everything will be done in the context of the image rather than the host machine.